# Directed graph nodes: Keep track of successors and predecessors

Tags: python, directed-graph

I am trying to implement a class `Node` representing a node in a directed graph, which in particular has a set of successors and predecessors. I would like `Node.predecessors` and `Node.predecessors` to behave like sets, in particular I want to iterate over their elements, add and remove elements, check containment, and set them from an iterable. However, after `node_1.sucessors.add(node_2)` it should be True that `node_1 in node_2.pedecessors`.

It seems possible to write a new subclass of `set` that implements this magic, but as far as I see an implementation of such a class would be quite cumbersome, because it would have to know about the `Node` object it belongs to and if it is a predecessor or successor and would need some special methods for addition and so on, so that `node_1.sucessors.add(node_2)` will not call `node_2.predecessors.add(node_1)` and thus lead to an infinite loop.

Generating one of the two attributes on the fly `(node for node in all_nodes if self in node.sucessors)` should be possible, but then I need to keep track of all Nodes belonging to a graph, which is easy (adding it to a `weakref.WeakSet` class attribute in `__init__`) if I have only one graph, but using one big set for all nodes leads to large computational effort if I have multiple disjoint graphs, and I do not see how to modify the set of predecessors.

Does anybody have a good solution for this?

Comment: Why doesn't your node just have an actual set stored in the attributes `predecessors` and `successors`?

Comment: In any case, without code or details of your larger design, you won't get much help.

Comment: I would like the class logic to make sure that the sets are consistent all the time, so that I don't need to add `node_1` explicitly to `node_2.pedecessors` after `node_1.sucessors.add(node_2)`.

Comment: And I want a puppy, but this is programming: there is no magic. Just do what afruizc suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you wrap the add method in your class and then inside that wrapper method you just use the two attributes predecessors and sucessors. Something like this

That's the first solution that would come to my mind:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self):
        self.pred = set()
        self.suce = set()

    def addSucessor(self, node):
        self.suce.add(node)
        node.pred.add(self)
```